# Does boost locale supports UTF-8 as internal encoding for char* based strings and streams

Tags: c++, encoding, utf-8, boost-locale

Internally I can use char or wchar_t for the application internal encoding of my strings and streams. char* can hold single byte encoded data or multibyte encoded data. For example ascii and UTF-8. I could use char8_t, char16_t or char32_t to clarify the internal encoding. But these character types are not supported properly by boost locale yet. Is it save to assume that boost locale uses utf-8 as internal encoding when using `std::basic_string<char>` and and `std::basic_fstream<char>` and others?

Example:

```
// Source file is encoded in UTF-8

boost::locale generator gen;
std::locale loc = gen("de_DE.UTF-8");
std::cout.imbue(loc);
std::string text = "Die Höhle des Löwen\n"s;
std::cout << text; // Correctly handles 'ö' on all platforms.
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this documentation yes on **Windows**:
https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/locale/doc/html/default_encoding_under_windows.html

On other platforms usually `char *` is treated as `utf-8` encoded string